# php-curl cannot authenticate to web service running on same machine using NTLM credentials

Tags: php, iis, php-curl

I have a php web application (php 7.4, IIS) that is attempting to authenticate to a .NET Core REST API running on IIS. The services are on the same machines.

I can successfully authenticate using Postman from another machine, but when I try the same request in code it fails with 401.1. An examination of the IIS failed request tracing logs indicates that the headers are somewhat different.

Clearly something is wrong with the curl request. I'd post that code here but it's being generated by a wrapper and I don't want to include all of that. But here are the FRT logs.

Failed request:

[image: Failed request headers]

[image: Failed request authentication]

Successful request:

[image: Successful request headers]

[image: Successful request authentication]

Is there a way to trace that raw request on the client? Clearly php-curl is sending a different authorization header than Postman.

Comment: The key is code. The problem lies in how to send authentication information in the code.

Comment: Does the browser have no pop-up window for you to enter your account password credentials?